# Concatenating php date type variable with other strings while creating a custom file name in php

Tags: filenames

I have been trying to use my variable $date of type date to concatenate with some other string so as to make a custom file name which I will use it in my program.I tried the following ways after going through some links but I failed.

```
$bar="foo".$date.".txt";

$bar="foo".string($date).".txt";

$bar="foo"."$date".".txt";
```

It always omits $date variable and creates a file with name foo.txt. But I am looking for some thing like foo4/2/15.txt if value of $date is 4/2/15.
That would be great if some one help me with this.

Comment: Are you certain `$date` has a value?

Comment: Yup.. I read a value from a file and store it in $date. I echoed it and it stores successfully.

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, but `$mydate = date('c'); $filename = "one".$mydate."two"; echo($filename);` works fine for me. I think you're looking for an error in the wrong place. Echo the filename you're building. Make sure you're looking in the right spot for the new file. Etc.

Comment: That works for me either if I echo. But the problem comes when I create a file. When I create a file with file name as "$filename" it shows foo.txt instead of "foo2/4/15.txt". However I came to know that Ubuntu doesnt accept "/" in its file name.So I replace "/" with "-". But its the same.

Comment: I get that `/` isn't an accepted character, but the thing is you should be getting an error when you try to create the file; it shouldn't just magically drop the illegal characters -- that doesn't make any sense: no API in the world looks at a filename and says "There are illegal characters in this filename, so I'll just drop some parts until I can save it." One of your assumptions must be mistaken.

Comment: Yup I realised that. Trying catching the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Got the bug. It seems silly but may help some one in the same situation one or the other day.

1. My definition for $date is in a loop and the last definition was becoming null.So it always doesn't take any value for $date resulting foo.txt instead of foo2/4/15.txt.
2. As we discussed in the comments we also gotta take care of illegal file names.

Thanks for people above for their time.